# Line break in php wordpress not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, email, woocommerce

```
<p><?php _e( "Beste ".$_POST['billing_first_name']. " ".$_POST['billing_last_name'].", \n"." Wij hebben uw bestelling ontvangen. Als wij alle benodigde gegeven hebben ontvangen zullen we de definitieve startdatum van het abonnement bepalen. Mocht u vragen hebben dan kunt u bellen naar het telefoonnummer. \n
U heeft bij ons het volgende lokalisatie pakket besteld.", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

The following text is used to generate an email that is sent to a custommer after filling the woocommerce form. Im trying to add a line break in certain parts using `\n` This is not working. The email comes in without any line breaks. Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: look at your html source. You will see the linebreaks are in fact there. You may want to use `nl2br` if you're wanting to write to anything.

Comment: also, the method you're sending email as, is unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `\n` with `<br />`.

You are sending it as HTML, so use HTML linebreaks.

Answer (score 1):

If your email is in HTML, you need to use HTML to create line breaks. `<br>` is a line break tag. You can also wrap each paragraph in `<p>...some text...</p>` tags to create line breaks between paragraphs.